# How to model inheritance with extern classes in UML class diagramms?

Tags: java, uml

How do you represent Inheritance in a UML class diagramm if the base class is not part of the module.
Say e.g. you have a class myScene (in your diagramm) that extends the javafx.scene.Scene, how do you show this relationship?

Comment: I tend to draw up the classes even if they are not designed by me, then I represent them in a different colour and add a comment to communicate this.

Comment: So you just add them but with or wthout methods? I'm afraid that adding all methods would just blow up the whole thing too much.

Comment: It depends on the model's purpose. If documenting a domain model for other to reference, then I would put in everything. If the purpose of the diagram is to give an abstract overview then I supposed inheriting from an empty "javafx.scene.Scene" would be ok -- again while adding a comment.

Comment: Do as @Pétur said. That's fine. You can leave away class details.

Comment: @Pétur you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to draw up the classes even if they are not designed by me, then I represent them in a different colour and add a comment to communicate this.

In a comment you asked:

> So you just add them but with or wthout methods? I'm afraid that
>   adding all methods would just blow up the whole thing too much.

It depends on the model's purpose. If documenting a domain model for other to reference, then I would put in everything. If the purpose of the diagram is to give an abstract overview then I supposed inheriting from an empty "javafx.scene.Scene" would be ok -- again while adding a comment.